# python how to loop functions

Tags: python, for-loop, counter

the code I have is below, using spyder on a windows OS

```
import numpy 
catch_rate = 0.5 
def tenMiss(throws):
    for i in range(len(throws) - 3): # loop through the throws
        print(sum(throws[i:i+3] < catch_rate))
        if sum(throws[i:i+3] < catch_rate) == 0: # total misses out of 10 throws
            print("ten Misses!")
            return True 
        return False
throws = numpy.random.random(20)
print (tenMiss(throws))
```

I am trying to loop this function 700 times with a "for" loop then add a count variable to determine how many times the function returns true. the trouble im having is determining wthat variable should go into the for loop to "choose" this function to be whats looped. and once i get there how would i incorporate the count variable

Comment: The inner loop of your function is executed only once. Is that intentional?

Comment: yes it was intentional to only run the function once. if you think it would be better to run the function multiple times i would love to here why.

Comment: Then why do you need the loop at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
true_count = 0
for x in range(700):
    result = some_function()
    if result is True:
        true_count += 1
print('True was returned %d times' % true_count)
```

Comment: John thanks for the reply, is some_function() a variable or is it meant to actually be a function?

Comment: @natedowg2000 It's meant to be a function.  In your case it would be your `tenMiss()` function, but I wanted to provide a general solution that could be used with any such function.